# CSS left-align a float but constrain by right margin

Tags: css, css-float

Is there a CSS way to have a an inline block be left aligned, yet when the container becomes to small be constrained by the right edge, and instead have what is at the left of the block be reduced, and honor text-ellipsis ?

When the container is wide I want something like

```
Some longish text goes here [My Block]            |<- right edge
```

and when the container is narrow

```
Some longish...[My Block] |<- right edge
```

ideally **it should be dynamic and fluid when container is resized**.

**The longish test and the text of "My Block" are not constant, and neither are their width** (so using a table with fixed layout does not work, and a regular table does not allow the text-ellipsis to work)

**edit:** illustration

[image]

**edit 2:** bolded the fact widths are not known, so any solution involving a css with a text or block width expressed in pixels or percents will not work :(

Comment: have you tried anything

Comment: not very clear what you mean, may be an image would help

Comment: @Naeem yes, table-based approaches.

Comment: @gaurav added illustration image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with flexible layout and flex-shrink, which comes out very short & simple. It won't work on older IE and Android <= 4.3

Testable snippets: http://jsbin.com/nodironodo/1/edit?html,css,output

Code for reference below without the cosmetic aspects

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ellipsis">Some longish text goes here</div>
  <div class="block">My Block</div>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` with `text-overflow: ellipsis`. Have a look at the below url:

http://jsfiddle.net/jjmxL9hr/

I hope this solves your clarification. Let me know for any clarification.

Comment: Does not seem to work: if you resize the result area in jsbin (and thus the size of the container), it does not affect the text ellipsis (the bloc wraps instead in your example).

Comment: if resize if the only issue, use it along with media query with preferred breakpoints.

Comment: media queries means you need to know the width, and the widths are not fixed, neither that of the longish text nor of the block

Answer (score 0):

Using media queries should do it.

```css
.container{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container > p{
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 0;
}

.container > div{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  html .container > p{
    max-width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text-primary">Some longish text goes here some longish text goes here</p>
  <div class="my-block">[My Block]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work, when you resize to small sizes the block becomes right-aligned, also the width are not known (neither of the longish text nor the block) as the texts are dynamic (come from a db)

Comment: Edited my snippet (I misunderstood the right edge thing as floating right). Also, I don't think it's possible to apply text overflow without specifying width.

Comment: Found a solution with flexible layout